# The background image in my div went away in html

Tags: html, css, background-image

So the issue is within the "cover" div. I had the background image in place and good to go until I started making everything responsive and now it does not show up at all, even on desktop. If there is a good workaround for this I would appreciate it. I've tried all that I knew how.

CSS

```
.cover {
background-image:url("images/rendering.png");
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
border-bottom:#F4EC1F solid 10px;
}

.cover p {
width: 50%;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top:20px;
text-align:center;
font-size:24px;
position:relative;
}

.cover h1 {
margin:0;
text-align:center;
max-width:100%;
}

.cover h2 {
margin:0;
text-align:center;
max-width:100%;
font-weight:bolder;
font-size:48px;
color:#002D51;
}
```

HTML

```
<!--Header-->
<div class="cover">
<h1><img src="images/logo_03.png" /></h1>
<h2>Coming Soon!</h2>
<p>(I-215 & South Rainbow)</p>
<p>
<div id="countdown" align="center"><!--Countdown -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<script type="application/javascript">
var myCountdown2 = new Countdown({

                                    year    : 2014,
                                    month   : 11, 
                                    day     : 1,
                                    width   : 400, 
                                    height  : 72,

                                    numbers     :   {
                        font    : "Arial", // Arial Times Verdana etc... see "numberMarginTop" above to correct vertical centering
                        color   : "#FFFFFF",
                        bkgd    : "#002d51",
                        rounded : 0.15,             // percentage of size 
                        shadow  : {
                                    x : 5,          // x offset (in pixels)
                                    y : 7,          // y offset (in pixels)
                                    s : 9,          // spread
                                    c : "#FFF", // color
                                    a : 0.4         // alpha    // <- no comma on last item!
                                    }
                    },

                        labels  :   {
                                    font    : "Arial",
                                    color   : "#002d51",
                                    weight  : "normal"                      // <- no comma on last item!
                                    }                                           // <- no comma on last item!

})
</script>




<!-- =========================================================== -->
</div><!--END Countdown -->









</div>
<!--END Header-->
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/03odbqqo/1/). Are you sure the path to your image is correct? What was the change you made that made the background disappear?

Comment: You have an extra opening `<p>` tag but you don't close it. Not likely the problem, but you should remove it. What did you change?

Comment: In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rrhk4w2/7/), I found nothing wrong with what you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  background:url("..//images/rendering.png");
```

instead of this

```
 background-image:url("images/rendering.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

The image link was broken some how thanks everyone!